# Error when boost signals2 connect with void() bound

Tags: c++, boost, boost-signals2

When I try to compile this code I get the error

> In constructor 'Foo::Foo()': 15:40: error: 'bind' was not declared in
>   this scope

```
#include <functional>
#include <boost/signals2.hpp>

class Foo {
public:
    Foo();
    void slot1(int i);
    void slot2();
    boost::signals2::signal<void (int)> sig1;
    boost::signals2::signal<void ()> sig2;
};
Foo::Foo() {
    sig1.connect(bind(&Foo::slot1, this, _1));  //  O K !
    sig2.connect(bind(&Foo::slot2, this));      //  E R R O R !
}
void Foo::slot1(int i) { }
void Foo::slot2() { }

int main() {
  Foo foo;
  foo.sig1(4711);
  foo.sig2();
}
```

What irritates me is that `sig1.connect(...)` works but not `sig2.connect(...)`.
If I use boost::bind() instead it works also on `sig2.connect(...)`

```
sig2.connect(boost::bind(&Foo::slot2, this));        // O K !
```

Can somebody explain why bind() works with slot1 but not slot2?

Here the code to "play" with it online: http://cpp.sh/32ey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sig1 works because the argument `_1` is refers to a type in the `boost` namespace.  This allows the compiler to find `boost::bind` through ADL, since it is in the same namespace.   However, sig2 does not, since none of the arguments are in the `boost` namespace.

You will either need to say `using namespace boost`, `using boost::bind`, or explicitly make the call to `boost::bind` to resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation